# How do I decode an image/pdf file properly in python3

Tags: python, unicode

I'm sending a file as follows.

```
with open(file,'rb') as f:
    rh=f.read()
```

Now to send it I'm using

```
sock.sendto(rh, (ip,port))
```

While receiving I'm trying to decode this as follows.

```
dat = sock.recvfrom()
data=dat.decode('ascii')
```

Then I'm writing this to a file. This works perfectly fine in case of a text file. But If I'm sending and receiving a image/pdf file, I get this error ..

```
File "code.py", line 16, in <module>
    data=dat.decode('ascii')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm not able to find out what's the problem here. I have also used dat.decode('utf-8') but no use

Comment: Why do you want to decode binary files using any encoding?

Comment: While trying to send the file I'm encoding it and at the receiving end I'm writing this to a file so I'm guessing I should decode it before trying to write it.

Comment: where are you encoding it?

Comment: I'm reading the file in  binary and sending it, sorry not encoding it.

Comment: try writing it without decoding to binary file.

Comment: it's working without decoding thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Try opening the file using `codecs`.

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open(filepath, encoding="ISO8859-1")
```

Worked for me when I was uploading a PDF file using an API.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to decode.  You read and sent the file in binary mode, so write the received file in binary mode.  `encode`/`decode` is meant for translating Unicode text to and from a binary representation.

```
with open(output_filename,'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```